# VBA if and multiple statements

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to ensure that all fields are filled on a form that i am creating however I am having some trouble with multiple if statements.

```
If Not IsEmpty(barcode) And Not IsEmpty(takenstock) And Not IsEmpty(staff) And Not IsEmpty(jobnumber) Then

    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 1).Value = staff
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = Product
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = ProductCode
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 4).Value = takenstock
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = jobnumber
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = Mydate
    Sheet2.Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = Mytime
    'removes stock from list of products
    Sheets("List of products").Range(findproduct).Value = selectproduct - takenstock
    'clears sheet
    Sheet1.Range("b1").Value = ""
    Sheet1.Range("b6").Value = ""
    Sheet1.Range("b5").Value = ""
    Sheet1.Range("b7").Value = ""
Else
    MsgBox "Please fill Barcode, stock to be taken,staff field and the job number" & vbNewLine & "Thank you", vbOKOnly, "Missing fields"

End If
```

This was my first attempt which didn't work, so i tried

```
If Not IsEmpty(barcode) And Not IsEmpty(takenstock) Then
    if Not IsEmpty(staff) And Not IsEmpty(jobnumber) Then
```

I have also tried removing the second Not's

Feels like I have tried everything but the code just isn't interested

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
If (Not IsEmpty(barcode)) And (Not IsEmpty(takenstock)) And 
    (Not IsEmpty(staff)) And (Not IsEmpty(jobnumber)) Then
```

Always err on the side of more parenthesis...

Also, it depends on what Type `barcode`, `takenstock`, `staff`, and `jobnumber` are.  I can't see your declarations.

If you declared them as `Range` and set them with something like

```
set barcode = Range("B7")
```

or something to that effect, your code should work fine.  But if you declared them as `String` or `Integer` types and set them with

```
barcode = Range("B7").value
```

then your expression will always evaluate `FALSE`.  `isEmpty()` is only for objects, not primitive types.

Comment: When in doubt: Add more parenthesis

Comment: I have tried playing around using parenthesis, still no luck :(

Comment: In that case, what type are `barcode`, `takenstock`, `staff`, and `jobnumber`?  Are they cell ranges, strings, integers,...?

Comment: barcode, staff and jobnumber are As String and takenstock As Integer, do you think this could be affecting it?

Comment: Integers are 0 (zero) as default. So I don't think that `IsEmpty()` will work very well on those.

Comment: This was the issue, this is so infuriating that it felt so simple. So the above code worked it simply was my lack of knowledge on using isempty() with the Declaration types.